# Combine two CSV files by comparing row values and skip if there is no match

Tags: php, csv, opencsv, fgetcsv

I have two CSV files.
The second file contains a lot more rows than the first file.
I only need the one's that match, and then create a final CSV file.
The zeros needs to be removed.

File 1 Example:

```
123123 | 3
123124 | 4
123125 | 5
```

File 2 Example:

```
0000000000123123 | 03 | Out of assortment
0000000000123124 | 04 | Out of stock
0000000000123125 | 05 | Instock
0000000000123126 | 00 | ZZ - Not in file 1
0000000000123127 | 00 | ZZ - Not in file 1
```

Result File:

```
123123 | 03 | Out of assortment
123124 | 04 | Out of stock
123125 | 05 | Instock
```

If there is no match then skip.
Only create a new CSV with matches.

This is what if found and try to get it to work. But my knowledge with PHP is not so good.

````
    $source = $result = array();

    $csvHandleOne = fopen('MAT_STAT_WHOLESALE_NL.csv', "r");
    while($data = fgetcsv($csvHandleOne, 2048, ",")) {
        
        $result[] = $data;
        ltrim($result, "0");
    }
    fclose($csvHandleOne);

    $csvHandleTwo = fopen('voorraad.csv', "r");
    while($data = fgetcsv($csvHandleTwo, 2048, ",")) {
        //We are interested only in SKU and ID link
        $source = $data[0];
    }
    fclose($csvHandleTwo);

    $csvHandleResult = fopen('result.csv', "w");
    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
        if($key && isset($source[$value[0]])) {
            //SKU => ID link found in source. Set id to $result
            $value[0] = $source[$value[0]];
        }
        
        fputcsv($csvHandleResult, $value, ',');
    }
    fclose($csvHandleResult);```
````

Comment: Show us what you have tried, it helps us to understand the question if nothing else

Comment: Which columns should "match"? The 1st, the 2nd, or both? I would recommend to use the `join` command.

Comment: Only the first columns have to match. And that was very difficult with my knowledge on php because it has zero's in the second file. If i should post what i have tried today this page would be full ;-)

Comment: Why should "Out of assortment" be left? It does not match?

Comment: Because I need to import it later on into the webshop.

Comment: It does not make sense. You say "If there is no match then skip". Then only "123123 | 03 " should be left. and not "123123 | 03 | Out of assortment " !?

Comment: oke...  file one has more rows with numbers then file two. I only need a file with the matching numbers.If there is no match then I dont need it in the new file. Thank you

Comment: **File one:** 
`123123 | 3 
123124 | 4 
123125 | 2  
123126 | 1
123127 | 0
123127 | 5`

**File two:**

`0000000000123123 | 03 | Out of assortment 
0000000000123124 | 04 | Stock 
0000000000123125 | 02 | Order`

**Result:**

`123123 | 03 | Out of assortment 
123124 | 04 | Stock
123125 | 02 | Order`